# I am getting to see error System.config is not a function in browser console

Tags: angular, typescript, systemjs

I am new to Type scripts, and I am getting the below error.

```
Uncaught TypeError: System.config is not a function
    at systemjs.config.js:53
    at systemjs.config.js:55
```

please let me know what more details you need

----- edited to add below-----

Below is my systemjs.config.js, please suggest how to migrate the same to 2.0.2 version of systemjs

```
/**
 * System configuration for Angular 2 samples
 * Adjust as necessary for your application needs.
 */
(function (global) {

  // map tells the System loader where to look for things
  var map = {
    'app': 'app', // 'dist',

    '@angular': 'node_modules/@angular',
    'rxjs': 'node_modules/rxjs'
  };

  // packages tells the System loader how to load when no filename and/or no extension
  var packages = {
    'app': { main: 'app.boot.js', defaultExtension: 'js' },
    'rxjs': { defaultExtension: 'js' }
  };

  var ngPackageNames = [
    'common',
    'compiler',
    'core',
    'forms',
    'http',
    'platform-browser',
    'platform-browser-dynamic',
    'router',
  ];

  // Individual files (~300 requests):
  function packIndex(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: 'index.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Bundled (~40 requests):
  function packUmd(pkgName) {
    packages['@angular/' + pkgName] = { main: '/bundles/' + pkgName + '.umd.js', defaultExtension: 'js' };
  }

  // Most environments should use UMD; some (Karma) need the individual index files
  var setPackageConfig = System.packageWithIndex ? packIndex : packUmd;

  // Add package entries for angular packages
  ngPackageNames.forEach(setPackageConfig);

  var config = {
    map: map,
    packages: packages
  };

  System.config(config);

})(this);
```

Comment: `System.config` is supported only by SystemJS version 0.x, not 2.x.  If you want to use `System.config` or you are following a tutorial that uses it, make sure to load a 0.x version of SystemJS (e.g, version 0.21.5).

Comment: ok..., what should I use instead of System.config. or what is System.config is replaced with?

Comment: That is beyond my knowledge of SystemJS, but you might get more help if you add your call to `System.config` to the question, since my understanding is that some settings have SystemJS 2.x equivalents and others don't.

Comment: added, hoping to get a resolution

Comment: What is the fix for this issue? I am facing same problem with my old app.